# Silverlight device independent coordinates

Tags: silverlight, pixel

I've written a Silverlight application that does not scale when I change from 96 dpi to 120 dpi The text and graphics does not change physical size on the screen as measured by a ruler.  I've read in various places that Silverlight should adjust to changes in DPI configuration.  The non-Silverlight portion of the web page scales as expected.  It seems as if the Silverlight plugin is using Pixels as the unit of measure rather than 1/96 inch.  What's the explanation?

I'm running Windows XP and setting the DPI in Wndows XPdesktop properties / settings / general / DPI Setting.

Comment: Known bug.  Dave Relyea (2/16/2008), on Silverlight.net:

Silverlight uses device-indendent pixels, where each pixel is 1/96 of an inch. This is also the most common device resolution.  Unfortunately, it is broken at high DPI settings right now...96 Silverlight pixels are always 96 device pixels

Answer (score 0):

This wont help if you're after measurable coordinates (ie: displaying an accurate ruler in your app), but if you want your UI to be resolution independent, you can wrap it with a ViewBox, which is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight)