# what resolution should I use in my code to test if a table runs off the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a large amount of tables which I have created a script to count the tables height and I will add a class to the table if it runs off the page in order for it to do a page break. The only thing im not sure of is what the pixel height I should be testing against for a letter size page?

Comment: thank you ... do you happen to know what the dpi is in a firefox print preview it seems to be way smaller than 300 dpi

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=how+many+pixels+in+a+8.5+x+11+page

**EDIT**

On second thought, forget pixels. Use CSS and specify it in inches. https://stackoverflow.com/a/935977/259457

Answer (score 0):

For A4 use 842px as height.

For printing purposes generate a pdf. That is much safer.

-- edit
Print.css is perfect for simple print such as notes / to do lists.

Comment: i have already created a print css and it will work fine my only problem is not knowing when to set a page break due to pixels how would a pdf help?

Comment: Generated pdf's create a stable version of the print no mather which browser / OS. print.css is fine for quick prints.

Comment: so I would generate a pdf from my webpage? and how would I be able to control the problem of tables being cut off in a pdf