# Silverlight: Does these recommendations still apply to silverlight as they did to WPF (Device independent system, xaml artwork rather than bitmap)?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I did quite a bit of developing with WPF and now moving over to silverlight.

In WPF the following existed and i wanted to see if they are still apparent using Silverlight or its changed? or something else is preferred?

1. WPF uses device independent pixels so you can scale up and down without distorting, i presume silverlight uses these measurements also? or is it pixels?
2. WPF recommended not including any Bitmap art but using XAML art otherwise images will become distorted when scaled up / down. Does this apply to silverlight?
3. What is the recommendations for using images for toolbar pictures - we can use bitmaps / icons or some other special way?

Anything else i might need to know before making the change?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The main issues using bitmaps will be bandwidth usage. So whenever possible, use styles and xaml. However, trying to design small icons in xaml is a painful and long process. A few kbytes bitmap wins imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) "all content is indeed resolution independent like WPF"

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/1695/4209.aspx

but not :)

[Silverlight device independent coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479758/silverlight-device-independent-coordinates)

2) Same here.. XAML is better..

3) There is only two 'native' images format supported PNG, JPEG

4) Forget about 'triggers'.. Silverligth use 'visual states'

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/06/10/visual-state

5) There is no bildin 'Menu', 'Toolbar' controls, but you could easily find 3rd party controls... google will help you

6) Silverlight is slower than WPF...